# Install tool to create virtual directory on IIS

Tags: iis, installation, virtual-directory

What install tool can I use to create Virtual Directory on IIS? OpenSource, free or to do in C#.

Comment: IIS6, II7? they have different APIs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) can create IIS virtual directories.

Answer (score 2):

You can create IIS virtual directorys using NAnt and the MKIISdir task in the NAntContrib project

Comment: NAnt is a build tool, not an install tool.

Comment: Actually NAnt can be much more than a build tool, but in this instance  I believe you are correct, as Mariano is probably seeking an installer for a windows executable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the VS.NET Web Setup Project included into visual studio.

Check this [article](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/030806.htm) for a list of deployment possiblities for your web app :

Comment: I have used Web Setup Projects and they work very nicely. Both the virtual directory and the application are automatically created and you can control a lot of the default settings for the virtual directory. The actual installation process is very simple as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Microsoft Web Deployment Tool](http://blogs.iis.net/msdeploy/archive/2008/01/22/welcome-to-the-web-deployment-team-blog.aspx) to recreate a website structure.

Answer (score 0):

you can call a small VBScript from any installer via command line, and access the IIS object.

```
Set objMimeMap = GetObject("IIS://localhost/w3svc")
```